# how can i use browser sniffing in html through javascript?

Tags: css

i'm having a web page including HTML, CSS, javascript code, The problem is that when i use internet explorer then the divisions and margins of web page is got changed, but its working fine in any other browser..
so can anybody help me regarding this issue..???

Comment: what do you mean by margins and divisions?

Answer (score 4):

Oh good god don't browser sniff UA's! use a lib like this:

http://www.modernizr.com/

Feature detection is what you want not browser sniffing :)

If it's just styling then use a CSS Reset:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

There's not much a CSS Reset can't solve, bad margins, padding. font-sizes, world hunger, cancer, it's all in there.